# `-` disappears when changing font in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context, verbatim, context-mkiv

This is my code:

```
\starttext
  \starttyping
    -- comment
  \stoptyping
\stoptext
```

It compiles fine:

[image]

However, if I change the font:

```
\usemodule[simplefonts][size=12pt]
\setmonofont[Source Code Pro]

\starttext
  \starttyping
    -- comment
  \stoptyping
\stoptext
```

One of the dashes disappears:

[image]

Why is that happening?

Comment: It might be a problem with ligatures.

Comment: @Manuel thought about that, but I tested using the font in my editor and it did not replace the two `--` with a ligature (my editor renders ligatures).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you load a monospaced font without any further information it will automatically enable the TeX ligatures (`tlig`) which includes `--` and `---`.  To prevent this, load the font with `features=none`.

Furthermore, the `simplefonts` module has been superseded by the `\definefontfamily` method which I show below.  To match the sizes of all fonts we apply some scaling.

```
\definefontfamily [source] [rm] [Source Serif Pro]     [scale=0.9]
\definefontfamily [source] [ss] [Source Sans Pro]
\definefontfamily [source] [tt] [Source Code Pro]      [features=none]
\definefontfamily [source] [mm] [TeX Gyre DejaVu Math] [scale=0.9]

\setupbodyfont[source,12pt]

\starttext
\starttyping
  -- comment
\stoptyping
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: * Furthermore, the simplefonts module has been superseded by the \definefontfamily* sadly not in the distribution I use :/

Comment: @flyx Which distribution do you use?  I use TL 2016.

Comment: Something on an old CentOS which is maintained by someone else, I cannot tell you exactly (this is the common infrastructure where everything has to compile).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I was not aware that there are TeX ligatures in addition to the ligatures the font may provide itself. This fixes it:

```
\setmonofont[Source Code Pro][features=none]
```